# React & Mobx: initialize stores with variables from other store

Tags: typescript, store, mobx, mobx-react

I'm building a demo app and I want to use a lot of random data. I'm trying to find the right way to initialize mobx stores in sequential way. I'm using TypeScript. There are lot more dependencies for my Collaborations (few other stores along the way) but here is roughly what I've tried:

**ItemStore.ts**

```
export class ItemStore {
  constructor() {
    this.setItems(createItems())
    this.loaded = true
  }
  @observable items: Array<ItemModel> = []
  @observable loaded: boolean = false
  setItems = (items: Array<ItemModel>) => {
    this.items = items
  }
}
export default new ItemStore()
```

**dummyItems.ts**

```
export const createItems = (): Array<ItemModel> => {
  const itemsNumber = randomInt(0, 10)
  let items: Array<ItemModel> = []
  for (var i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {
    items.push(createItem(
    uuid(), // id
    `item${i}`, // name
    ))
  }
  return items      
}
```

Next thing, where I'm getting a bit stuck, is that I want to use these item's IDs (created with `uuid`) to initialize another Store. What I've tried is using autorun and see if previous store initialized using a variable:

```
class CollaborationStore {
  constructor() {
   autorun(() => {
    if (ItemStore.loaded === true) {
      this.collaborations(createCollaborations())
    }
  }
  @observable collaborations: Array<CollaborationModel> = []
  setCollaborations = (collaborations: Array<ItemCollectionObject>) => {
    this.collaborations = collaborations
  }
}

export default new CollaborationStore()
```

**dummyCollaborations.ts**

```
import ItemStore from './ItemStore'

export const createCollaborations = () => {
  const collaborations: Array<CollaborationModel> = []
  ItemStore.items.forEach((item: ItemModel) => {
   collaborations.concat(
    createCollaboration(
     uuid(), // id
     `collabName`, // name
     item.id // itemId
    )
  })
  return collaborations
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the ItemStore.loaded gets set to true before all items are created (logging it to console) so the `CollaborationStore` does not initiate with right data. In my components I'm simply importing Stores and trying to access the observable variables.

**someComponent.tsx**

```
import CollaborationStore from '../CollaborationStore'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

...

const someComponent = observer(() => {

...

return (
 <div>{Collaborationstore.collaborations.map((item: CollaborationModel) => (
  <div>Collaboration.name</div>
 ))</div>
)
})
```

**What is the correct way of making sure one Store created all the items before another one starts getting its data?**